# C# Implementations of EventPublisher

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, event-handling

I know Microsoft Prism has an EventAggregator. And I also found [one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/event_aggregator.aspx) on CodeProject.

Is there any better alternatives?

Thanks

**Update:**

Just found a very similar question (posted in Feb 2010): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [nice implementation](http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/2010/04/event-aggregator-with-reactive.html) as well as a [good and related write up](http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/2010/04/event-aggregator-example.html) about event aggregation in general.

As a litmus test of 'goodness' this was the inspiration for the one used in the Caliburn framework.

HTH
Berryl

Answer (score 1):

For WPF/Silverlight. I've used and like the [Messenger Class](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx) from the [MVVM Light toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/). I think it could be used within windows forms too.

You use it like this(from above link):

```
// Somewhere
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, DoSomething);
// Further
private void DoSomething(string message)
{
    // ...
}
// Somewhere else
Messenger.Default.Send(“Hello world”)
```

See this for more info on MVVM Light:
http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's better, but I have implemented and maintain [MemBus](https://github.com/flq/MemBus), which I prefer describing more of a "In-Memory Publish/Subscribe Bus", but really it is rather easy to use it as Event Aggregator.

Publishing, Subscribing is quite pluggable, IoC support is easy to add, etc., etc. It requires .NET 4 and brings a lot of fun if you use the Rx Framework as MemBus can create IObservable implementations. You will find some [documentation here](http://realfiction.net/content/tag/membus)